# For what reason is released error 'Could not find class' in LogCat?

Tags: android, logcat

Once compiled, the error `class not found` is released in `LogCat`. 
These are the lines of the error:

```
03-25 20:17:54.490: E/dalvikvm(880): Could not find class 'br.ufpe.cin.five.api.synthesizer.Synthesizer', referenced from method com.example.hellowordfive2.HelloActivity2.instanciar
```

What are the possible reasons for this to happen?

Answer (score 2):

a: class does not exist

b: class not declared in manifest

c: class in wrong package

d: user error(bad typing)